# Pros and Cons of providing a summary of customer reviews in Ecommerce websites

Tags: e-commerce

Some ecommerce websites generate a summary of Pros and Cons based on user reviews for a particular product. This [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/01/product-reviews-ratings-ux/#provide-quick-summaries-of-pros-and-cons) recommends such a feature.

**What are some pros and cons for this feature? Have you encountered any research exploring this topic?**

The feature look like this:

[image]

Comment: I really don't know, but that image is strange. The negative review is clearly from a real client who had a bad experience, while the positive review is an "Incentivized Review." If I were a client, I would never trust this product! Also, clients who have had a bad experience are quite likely to leave a negative review in a ratio that could go as high as 20:1. The numbers here are quite uncommon. One link that might be of interest to you is https://www.inc.com/andrew-thomas/the-hidden-ratio-that-could-make-or-break-your-company.html.

Answer (score 0):

It is all in the Smashing Magazine article you linked to: users want more than just a "5 stars" rating, they want to see how ratings are distributed and as the article shows, they even tend to start by looking at the negative reviews, so they can understand how critical and relevant to them the issues mentioned in them are. From my own experience (and that of more people in my immediate vicinity) this pattern is likely to help the users when reviewing a product as it exposes valuable pieces of information: the rating as a decimal value, rating distribution, and both positive and negative reviews.